# Apache Authentication Refresh

Tags: perl, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to get a simple CGI website set up with Perl that creates an HTML page that links to a Java applet.  I have managed to set this up, but for some reason, the Apache authentication for the site is doing some wonky things.  Namely, if the password was entered incorrectly, instead of redirecting to a 403 page (as I assumed it should), it just refreshes the page - bringing up the password prompt again.  My htaccess file looks as follows:

```
AuthUserFile  PATH/TO/HTPASSWD
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName  NAME
AuthType Basic
require user USER1
```

and it is located in the Java applets directory (different from the CGI directory).  I have been looking around as to why this problem occurs, but I can't seem to find a reason the page would be refreshed.  Does anyone know if this behaviour is typical if a Perl CGI program is trying to access an applet with .htaccess in the applet folder?  Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It's "Perl", not "PERL".

Answer (score 1):

It returns the more appropriate 401 Unauthorized error. The response includes the authentication method (Basic). Browsers respond to that by displaying a login prompt. (I believe the browsers give you a 401 error page after a few attempts.)

This is appropriate behaviour. You want to the user to be given another chance to enter his user/password. The real problem is that you can't customize the error to include other links (for example). The name "Basic" is merited.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense.  However, I don't ever get a 401 page, no matter how many login attempts are made.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: Maybe if you press Esc or the Cancel button? It's browser-specific behaviour, and I was going from memory.

Comment: nope, it ALWAYS retries.  Occasionally this behaviour even breaks windows browsers, because you cannot stop it for asking you for a password.  That is the reason for the question in the first place:P

Comment: You hav ethe dumbest browser ever if you can't cancel out of the dialog. Every browser I've tried since 1995 can do that (Netscape, lynx, IE, Firefox, Chrome). I suppose you could put JS in your 401 error document that makes the browser redirect right back to that page, but that would be a pretty dumb thing to do on purpose.

Comment: Just tried them all again to be sure. (Except Netscape, obviously)

Comment: I agree, I have never seen this behaviour in any of my previous websites, which is why I'm scratching my head.  For whatever reason, I quite literally cannot get a 401 page with any browser on any OS, it refreshes every single time.  I don't suppose you have any idea as to what you would have to do in the Apache config to MAKE this happen, so I can check if that is an issue?

Comment: What's the server's response?

Comment: It refreshes the page by default, which brings the prompt up again, even if you cancel.  I think it has something to do with the user being allowed to run the CGI, but not being allowed to grab the java applet linked to by the CGI.  At that point,  Apache can't just return a 401 for the applet, or if it does, I guess the browser doesn't know what do do with a full page but a 401'd applet so it refreshes?